# How to change received data in Model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, kohana

I have a typical function in model which is receiving 'time' from table 'Orders':

```
public function get_time() {
    $result = array();
    $result = DB::select('id', 'time', 'description')->from('orders')->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

The problem is, that 'time' field is stored in MySQL in format (TIME): `'HH:mm:ss'`, example: 11:45:00.

But I don't need seconds, so I can do: `date('H:i', strtotime($time));`
Doing this in a View isn't good idea. I need to do this conversion in Model or Controller.
Of course:

```
$result['time'] = date('H:i', strtotime(result['time']));
```

won't work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in the view is perfect, it's formatting the model result to be displayed correctly.

```
$result['time'] = date('H:i', strtotime(result['time']));
```

There is a syntax error, you forgot to prefix `result` with the dollar sign.

---

What zombor said was important too (I missed it)

> $result is a database result iterator object, not a single result

Comment: Also, $result is a database result iterator object, not a single result.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at TIME_FORMAT function:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('11:45:00', '%H:%i')
```

result in `11:45`. Change the code like this:

```
$result = DB::select('id', array('TIME_FORMAT("time", '%H:%i')', 'formatted_time'), 'description')->from('orders')->execute();
```